# input range updating value while changing value

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to create an `<input>` range which updates the value after a user is done chaning. It will trigger a javascript function when it is done with changing the range bar. For example:

```js
function updateTextInput(val) {
  let output = document.getElementById('umjp_minutes');
  output.innerText = val;
}
```

```html
<input id="umjp_minutePicker" type="range" min="15" max="100" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">
<span id="umjp_minutes">40</span>
```

To give a user a more rich experience I want the range `<input>` to be updated **while** the user is changing. What is the most simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: As a hint, instead of "while sliding" you phrased it as "while _changing_", a more generic term, you'd find the DOM event `onchange`. The [DOM Event API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) makes available a rich set of fancy events with fairly 'boring' names partly for that reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `onchange` event to `oninput` like here:

```js
function updateTextInput(val) {
  let output = document.getElementById('umjp_minutes');
  output.innerText = val;
}
```

```html
<input id="umjp_minutePicker" type="range" min="15" max="100" oninput="updateTextInput(this.value);">
<span id="umjp_minutes">40</span>
```

You can check all DOM events information and description [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp).

Comment: @WillemvanderVeen Don't forget to come back and accept it [once the timer runs out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250132/why-cant-i-accept-an-answer-in-the-first-15-minutes-after-asking-the-question).